# Scripts still run after script elements removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why do scripts still run after their tags get removed?

I was testing jQuery to remove style and link tags to remove CSS styles when i accidentally typed 'script' instead of 'style' for the selector. But what happened is that the scripts defined in those tags still run. Why is that?

[here's a sample in JS](http://jsfiddle.net/taXNf/):

```
//assume foo is defined
foo();

var scripts = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script')),
    current;

//remove all scripts
while (scripts.length) {
    current = scripts.pop();
    current.parentNode.removeChild(current);
}

//foo still works
foo();​
```

[same thing with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/taXNf/1/):

```
foo();

$('script').remove();

foo();​
```

And a side question: If they don't get removed this way, what will?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They run because they are loaded into memory when the script is first parsed.

You can set anything to `undefined` to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

The first script has already run, and the second has been loaded, by the time you try to remove them.  It looks like:

```
<script>
function foo(){
alert('foo');
}
</script>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

foo();

var scripts = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script')),
    current;

while (scripts.length) {
    current = scripts.pop();
    current.parentNode.removeChild(current);
}

foo();
//]]>  

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
$('script:not([src], [type])', document).remove();
window.foo = false; // or, window.foo = undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<script>` tag just defines code that is run -- for instance

```
foo = function() { alert("Yay!"); };
```

assigns the function above to `window.foo`. I can't think of a bulletproof way (aside from an insane transactional memory implementation, perchance) to reverse the effects of any given block of code. (I have the gut feeling that there's a name for this problem.)

Of course if you want just a limited implementation, you could record the keys in `window` before and after the `<script>`'s run and then `delete` those that were created during that run when you want to. But again -- not bulletproof.